# Replacing newlines doesnt work

Tags: php, forms, email, html-email

I'm really getting annoyed because of my email form. I've got a form where visitors submits their question. After submitting the message etc. will first be stored in the database. When storing went succesfull, an email will be sent to my emailaddress.

That goes well,except of the message part. It keeps showing \r\n (those newlines are also stored in db) while I tried to str_replaced() the \r\n with 
 and even ntblr() it. Nothing works. What the heck am I doing wrong?

**Get the content of the message:**

```
$message = safe($mysqli,$_POST['message']);
```

The safe() function is: mysqli_real_escape_string

**Email code:**

```
if (!$stmt) {
        echo "sendingEmailError";   
    } else {

        //Send email
        $to = "<my@email.com>";         
        $subject = "Website message from ".$account."";
        $body = " 

        <div> ".nl2br($message)." </div>";

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: New email from '.$account.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);   

        echo "sendingEmailSuccess"; 

    }
```

The `\r\n`  should be replaced with `<br />`

Comment: Are you **SURE** that your text contains newline and carriage returns cars, or did those chars somehow get mangled and are now ``\``, `n`, ``\``, and `r` literals, e.g. `\r\n` as carriage return/newline is 2 bytes, `\r\n` as literal characters backslash, `r`, and `n` is 4 bytes. And in any case, you shouldn't be building your own mime emails. Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer, both of which make sending html emails trivial.

Comment: You can use PHP_EOL instead of \r\n

Comment: PHP_EOL is wrong in this case as it may be OS specific while `\r\n` has a special OS independant meaning here.

Comment: In addition to what @MarcB said, do a `var_dump($body)` and post the results.

Comment: @user986959: pointless. PHP_EOL is the local machine's eol chars. If the server is a Unix box, then PHP_EOL is `\n`, and won't match `\r\n` as submitted by a Windows box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mysqli_real_escape_string changed your linebreaks, usually by escaping them. After that your nl2br will no longer hit anything.

Try working with the original message and apply nl2br on that.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. You're absolutely right. Works as a charm now :')

Answer (score -1):

Did you try RegEX?

```
$message = preg_replace("/(\\n|\\r)+/ui", '<br />', $message);
```

Also, check the data from the mysql table, and it its escaped to a **stripslashes**.